# Trouble understanding if statement code

Tags: javascript, html

I am going through a book about HTML5 and there are two lines of code I cannot quite understand

```
var mp3Support,oggSupport;
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
if(audio.canPlayType) {
        mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3');
}
```

So, first you create an audio element and check if canPlayType method can be used?
Then, the code inside the if statement is some kind of ternary operation?

The audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3') outputs 'probably' and mp3Support is set to '' but after that line mp3Support outputs true. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, first you create an audio element

Yes

> and check if canPlayType method can be used?

The check is to see if `canPlayType` is a true value, but that amounts to the same thing in practical terms.

> Then, the code inside the if statement is some kind of ternary operation?

No.

`audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3')` can return a number of values, one of which is an empty string.

`"" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3');` tests to see if it not an empty string (and evaluates as `true` or `false`)

`mp3Support =` then is just assigned that `true` or `false`

It could be more clearly written as:

```
mp3Support = ("" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the really thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

```
 mp3Support = "" != audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3');
```

This combines a variable initialization with boolean expression.

in other way:

```
if(audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3')!="")
{
  mp3Support=true;
}
else
{
  mp3Support=false;
}
```